# how to solve error cs8804 in visual studio

Tags: c#

I get this error for all of my projects:

> Error CS8804  Cannot specify /main if there is a compilation unit with
> top-level statements. Project_Basics  D:\New
> folder\Project_Basics\Project_Basics\CSC

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Project_Basics
    {
        internal class Datatype2
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello wwwwwww");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that your project has file with a [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements) (usually it is `Program.cs`), usually it contains several expressions without curly braces, for example:

```cs
using System;

var i = 1;
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

You need either remove it, or remove the `Main` method from `Boxing` class (you can just move it's contents to the top-level statement file, another option - rename `Boxing.Main` to something like `Boxing.Do` and call it in the top-level statements file, or just move the contents of `test1` there and remove the `Boxing` class completely).

Read also:

- [Main() and command-line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line)
- [Top-level statements - programs without Main methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/top-level-statements)

Answer (score 0):

delete the file (c# Program.cs) in solution Explorer will solve the error

[image: delete the file marked red]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).